# BigQuery Percentile function could not be executed in the allotted memory over 30M rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to get the percentile distribution over a column of data. My query looks like this

```
#StandardSQL 
SELECT 
PERCENTILE_CONT(age, 0) OVER() AS min,
PERCENTILE_CONT(age, 0.05) OVER() AS percentile5,
PERCENTILE_CONT(age, 0.25) OVER() AS percentile25,
PERCENTILE_CONT(age, 0.50) OVER() AS percentile50,
PERCENTILE_CONT(age, 0.75) OVER() AS percentile75,
PERCENTILE_CONT(age, 0.95) OVER() AS percentile95,
PERCENTILE_CONT(age, 1) OVER() AS max
FROM `data`
```

However I keep running into the error

```
The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. 
OVER() operator used too much memory..
```

I've also tried running it one line at a time like

```
select PERCENTILE_CONT(age, 0.05) OVER() AS percentile5 
from data
```

but this also gives the same error.

My table has 30M rows. **Is there any way to optimise it?**

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use APPROX_QUANTILES instead? The problem is that PERCENTILE_CONT doesn't scale when the window is the entire table.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard It's good enough for 25th, 50th, 75th percentiles, but how about the 5th and 95th percentiles? I could do APPROX_QUANTILES(age, 20) then take the first and last bucket, but that's quite inelegant. Is this the only option? Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with getting the 5th and 95th percentiles? You can use `APPROX_QUANTILES(age, 100)[OFFSET(5)]`, for instance.

Comment: at least in my case, `APPROX_QUANTILES` is too approx. It changes by around 2% (which matters when trying to identify changes in quantiles).

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, `age` doesn't take on many values.  If so, you can summarize the data and then do what you want.

For instance:

```
select min(age) as min,
       max(case when running_cnt - cnt < 0.05 * cnt 
                then age
           end) as percentile_05
       max(case when running_cnt - cnt < 0.5 * cnt 
                then age
           end) as percentile_50
       max(age) as max
from (select age, count(*) as cnt,
             sum(count(*)) over (order by age) as running_cnt,
             sum(count(*)) over () as total_cnt
      from `data`
      group by age
     ) d
```

Answer (score 0):

I would order your data and then calculate the percentile rank manually. If you require interpolation, it can also be done manually...

```
WITH ORDERED AS (
 SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY age ASC) AS ROWNUM
FROM
  `data`
)
SELECT
  age AS percentile50
FROM
  ORDERED
WHERE
  ROWNUM = (
    SELECT CEILING(50 / 100.00 * (COUNT(*) + 1)) FROM ORDERED
  )
```

Comment: . . If the original data is getting a resources error, I'm guessing this one will as well.  Ordered analytic functions with no `partition by` can just be a problem in BigQuery.